# How do I extend an interface thats generic, with a class that should be generic for enums?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using a library to serialize objects, it supports custom converters to serialize/deserialize data.

In order to do this for enums you need to use custom converter that extends the following interface.

```js
export interface JsonCustomConvert<T> {
    serialize(data: T): any;
    deserialize(data: any): T;
}
```

This is what I currently have:

```js
@JsonConverter
export class MyEnumConverter implements JsonCustomConvert<MyEnumConverter> {
  serialize(val: MyEnumConverter): string {
    return MyEnumConverter[val];
  }
  deserialize(val: any): MyEnumConverter {
    const possibleValidEnum = (<any>MyEnumConverter)[val];
    if (possibleValidEnum === undefined) {
      throw Error();
    }
    return <MyEnumConverter>possibleValidEnum;
  }
}
```

The problem is obviously that you need a converter per enum.. Is there any way to get this working using a generic type on the class for any string indexed enum?

There is no point showing examples that I got so far since i'm learning the language, and any attempt just results in random errors.

**Edit:**

Here is a running example of my problem, needing an converter for every enum value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-t2kdyx

Comment: Which library are you using to serialize objects?

Comment: _"In order to do this for enums you need to use custom converter that extends the following interface."_ is a false statement.

Comment: @AluanHaddad whats the point of such a comment without an correctment

Comment: @Mathyn https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript

Comment: @Alt-rockninjacowgirl, fair enough, i'll clarify. In TypeScript, the `implements` only serves the purposes of eager type checking and self-documentation. It literally has no runtime impact, being 100% erased. Therefore it is impossible for a library to _require_ that it be used by definition.

Comment: @Alt-rockninjacowgirl I took a look at the library and this won't work unless they add a feature allowing you to specify constructor arguments to the Custom Converter class in the decorator expression.

Comment: @Alt-rockninjacowgirl could you provide a full example using the decorator? I think using a function to create the serializers for each enum could work but getting a sample to work is a bit too much time investment since there is no sample in the docs for the package for enums.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks, i've added a playground https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-t2kdyx

Comment: @AluanHaddad I see what you're saying, i'm afraid you're right, I can't get around "T is a type, but i'ts being used as an value". Would be alot easier if the object could be passed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a factory function that returns a class. The implementation will be the same for all enums, but the actual enum will be passed in as a parameter to the factory function:

```
import {
  JsonObject,
  JsonProperty,
  JsonConvert,
  JsonConverter,
  JsonCustomConvert,
} from "json2typescript";

enum A {
  a = "aa",
  b = "bb"
}

enum X {
  x = "xx",
  z = "zz"
}

function createConverter<T extends Record<keyof T, string | number>>(e: T){
  const reverseLookup = {} as  Record<T[keyof T], keyof T>
  for (const key of Object.keys(e) as Array<keyof T>) {
    reverseLookup[e[key]] = key;
  }
  @JsonConverter
  class EnumConverter implements JsonCustomConvert<T[keyof T]> {
    serialize(val: T[keyof T]): keyof T {
      return reverseLookup[val];
    }
    deserialize(val: keyof T): T[keyof T] {
      const possibleValidEnum = e[val];
      if (possibleValidEnum === undefined) {
        throw Error();
      }
      return possibleValidEnum as T[keyof T];
    }
  }
  return EnumConverter;
}


const XEnumConverter = createConverter(X);
const AEnumConverter = createConverter(A);

@JsonObject("User")
class User {
  @JsonProperty("aEnum", AEnumConverter)
  aEnum: A = A.a;
  @JsonProperty("xEnum", XEnumConverter)
  xEnum: X = X.x;
}

const jsonObj = {
  "aEnum": "a",
  "xEnum": "x"
};

let jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
let user: User = jsonConvert.deserializeObject(jsonObj, User);
console.log(user); // User {aEnum: "aa", xEnum: "xx"}

let r: User = jsonConvert.serializeObject(user);
console.log(r); // {aEnum: "a", xEnum: "x"}
```